# fetch sql records and store in a hashmap

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a script which is supposed to store the entire fetched table into a hashmap. So far, I have been able to fetch the records from MySQl database, but i am unable to store and display the records from the hashmap.
Please guide me to a correct code for the same.

The code so far:

```
public class myRow {
private int id;
private String name;
private int level;
private int m1;
private int m2;
private int m3;

// the constructor
public myRow( String n, int l,int m1, int m2, int m3) {

    this.name = n;
    this.level = l;
    this.m1 = m1;
    this.m2 = m2;
    this.m3 = m3;
}}
```

The main class is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt1 = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...\n\n");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

        stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        Map<Integer, myRow> map = new HashMap<Integer, myRow>(0);

        try {
            String sql="SELECT * FROM recs.new_table;";
            System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                myRow mr = new myRow(rs.getString(2), rs.getInt(3),rs.getInt(4),rs.getInt(5),rs.getInt(6) );
                map.put(rs.getInt(1), mr);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map.containsValue("mark"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" ERROR :: "+e); 
    }
```

The table records are in the following manner:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the issue you're having is?

Comment: @fdsa i want to store the table records from the database into a hashmap. And following that, I want to fetch and display the records from the hashmap. Though, I am able to get the records from database, I am unable to store and fetch from hashmap.

Comment: again what is the problem ?...exception...stack trace ?

Comment: You are trying to print the map straightaway. It will not be printed as you expected unless you implement toString() for the class myRow. The other way, you can iterate the map and print the values one by one using for loop.

Comment: Another point to be noted, map.containsValue("mark") will always returns false in your case because the values stored in the map are objects of type "myRow".

Comment: Please copy/paste the table into the question **as text** -- it is easier to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok to me, except for the line:

```
System.out.println(map.containsValue("mark"));
```

This will not find the row containing `mark`.  The `containsValue` relies on the object's `equals` method, and since you're passing a simple string, a `String` class object will never equal a `myRow` class so it will never find it.

To locate one of the rows in the map, you'll need some code like:

```
myRow findRowByName(String name) {
  for (myRow row : map.values()) {
    if (row.name.equals(name)) {
      return row;
    }
  }
}
```