# How do i put data from an SQL Database to a Hashmap?

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, hashmap

i need to retrieve data from an SQL database and put it in a hashmap , i'am a bit lost about how to do that especially with my given data types  , if anyone can help and explain to me the process it would be great , here's below my code :

```
public void load (Path p) throws DataLoadingException {
    try {
        
         String pathString = p.toString();
         Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+pathString);
         Statement s = c.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from PassengerNumbers;");
        
          
            while (rs.next()) {
                LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("Date"));
                int  flightnumber = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("FlightNumber"));
                int loadestimate = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("LoadEstimate"));
            }
         
            rs.close();
            c.close();
            
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here's what the data looks like in the SqlDb :

```
(PK TEXT)             (PK INTEGER)                     (INTEGER)
   Date                FlightNumber                   LoadEstimate
2020-07-01               618                              124
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32209625

Comment: Not really , i need to store 2 int values and the date value aswell , been stuck on the last one .

Comment: Could you make a class that has those three fields, and store objects of that class in your HashMap?

Comment: It has been advised below , i tried but it returned null .

Comment: Same schoolwork assignment: [*put 3 different values from database to Hashmaps*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65599976/642706)

Answer (score 0):

A Hashmap contains key-value pairs and maps each unique key to a value.

According to the SQL database info you have provided your table has a [composite primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key), in other words your primary key consists of two columns (a *date* of type TEXT and a *flightNumber* of type INTEGER).

As you know a primary key has unique values in order to help you make distinctions when querying data in a table. So, you should store in your hashmap as a key the primary key of your table.

Now, since your primary key consists of two columns and it's the combination of their values that helps you identify uniqueness, you can create an array or a list and store there the *date* and the * flightNumber*. Then, you will add to your hashmap this array/list as a key and the rest of the fields you want (in our case the *loadEstimate* of type INTEGER) as its value.

The above in code should be something like this:

```
HashMap<ArrayList<Object>, int> myMap = new HashMap<>(); //Create your hashmap

while (rs.next()) {
    LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("Date"));
    int  flightnumber = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("FlightNumber"));
    int loadestimate = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("LoadEstimate"));

    //Create array resembling the primary key
    ArrayList<Object> mapKey = new ArrayList<>();
    mapKey.add(date);
    mapKey.add(new Integer(flightnumber));

    //Store to Map the key and the value
    myMap.put(mapKey, loadestimate);
}
//then do sth with the hashmap
```

Notice that I create an array of generic objects of type Object in order to be able to store objects of different kind. This is possible, since they both subclasses of the class Object.

Also, the safe pattern in Java is to close your ResultSet, Statement, and Connection (in that order) in a finally block when you are done with them. So, after the catch block add this finally block:

```
finally {
    try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { s.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { c.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but i have a problem now , whenever i try to check the content of "myMap" this is what i get : if the first line of the data base was A , the second B and the third C , whenever i print it comes likes this :  A/ AB / ABC / .. etc if you understand what i'm trying to say

Comment: Maybe you don't iterate the map correctly, when trying to print its contents. You should use a foreach  statement to read its values. Please provide a snippet of how you are trying to print the map. Also, try using a debugger and some breakpoints to be certain that the resultSet contains values and that they are copied correctly to the map.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a Flight class, in which you can store all the three values as attributes, in that way you would be able to store the three values in one place.
This makes it possible to store each Flight object in a Hashmap<Integer,Flight>.
Something like the code below.

```
HashMap<Integer,Flight> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Flight>;
Integer key = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
            LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("Date"));
            int  flightnumber = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("FlightNumber"));
            int loadestimate = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("LoadEstimate"));
            Flight newFlight = new Flight(date,flightnumber,loadestimate);
            hashMap.put(key, newFlight);
            key++;
}
```

In this way you can access all data by itterating through the hashmap, since you know the size of it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's returning an empty hashMap.

Comment: The only way this would return an empty HashMap would be if there were no data returned by the result set.  Have you stepped through this with your debugger to make sure that the loop is being iterated?

Comment: Yes i did , it is but for some reason i dont get its returning null